# What would cause a VB.NET DLL to fail in IIS when it works well when called by executable code?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

For the last 5-6 months I have been fighting a battle with VB code calling a c++ DLL. I have asked numerous questions on StackOverflow only to have all of them voted out of existence.

I have finally found a way of compiling my code (no help from Stackoverflow) that will work well with the C++ DLL. It appears that when I compile my VB.NET module and I use a 4.0 framework it works perfectly, no more memory issues with calling c++. Frameworks > 4.0 cause the protected memory errors.

My VB.NET code is itself a DLL and I call it from both compiled .EXE programs as well as uncompiled vb.net code from ASP.NET. When I compile it into other VB.NET programs everything works well. When I run it from ASP.NET I get;

> Attempted to read or write protected memory.

This is the same error I would get when I previously compiled with a Framework > v4.0. I have modified my web.config file adding;

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0"/>
```

and

```
        <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4.0" />
            <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true" />
            <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false" />
        </compiler>
```

With no change in behavior. Since the memory error is similar to what I get when I execute this same code compiled with a framework > 4.0 my assumption is IIS is executing the code with a framework > 4.0.

The questions as best I can formulate them are;

How can I verify what framework the DLL is executing in?
How can I control that framework?

Hopefully this question lasts long enough to get an answer, rather than voted down the tubes.

Comment: Have you tried enabling 32bitapplication from IIS ApplicationPool ?

Comment: I have not. The purpose of this entire exercise is to convert everything to x64. I have recompiled all VB.NET code in "Any CPU" mode, and am using the x64 version of the c++ DLL. I will try it under the leave no stone unturned philosophy, however.

Comment: I tried enabling 32 bit applications, and the Oracle DLL immediately ralphs on its shoes.

Comment: @PaulStearns Please don't take this the wrong way, but your previous questions around this issue have been closed **because you simply have not provided enough information for us to assist you**. Interop issues are always a massive pain to debug, but you haven't even given some of the most *basic* detail (e.g the signature of the native method you're trying to call and how you are P/Invoking it from VB.NET, so we can compare the two to determine if there is an issue in the way you have written the P/Invoke call). [1/2]

Comment: @PaulStearns [2/2] As such, any answer we could provide would amount to little more than a guess, and Stack Overflow's rules around questions and answers specifically preclude guesswork. That does not imply that your issue lacks merit, or is not interesting, or is unworthy of our time, it just is what it is. Right now you will probably get more joy opening a support ticket directly with Microsoft and/or the provider of the C++ DLL.

Comment: @PaulStearns Personally, my guess would be that (a) your P/Invoke signature or memory marshalling is slightly off and .NET Framework 4.0 is accommodating it while 4.6.1 and IIS are not, (b) the C++ DLL is doing some not-so-kosher things with memory management and .NET 4.0 allows those shenanigans, but newer versions of the Framework and IIS do not, (c) some combination of the aforementioned two.